# Silverstripe 3.4+ / how combine certain boolean fields into CheckboxFieldSet?

Tags: checkbox, backend, silverstripe

By default Silverstripe renders each boolean field in a new line as checkbox in the backend. Is there an easy way to combine certain boolean fields of the actual object into a CheckboxFieldSet so the fields get rendered next to each other? That would save space and make it better readable.

I only want specific boolean fields in there though, not all fields (only Toaster, Microwave, BBQ). Here's a simplified example:

### House.php

```
class House extends DataObject {
private static $db = array (
    'Name'      => 'Varchar(100)',
    'Toaster'   => 'Boolean',
    'Microwave' => 'Boolean',
    'BBQ'       => 'Boolean',
    'Phone'     => 'Varchar(100)',
    'Public'    => 'Boolean'
);
public function getCMSfields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $amenities = new CheckboxSetField('Amenities'));

    return $fields;
}
```

$amenities would need a list of the wanted fields.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: If you just want to change the display in the cms, you can add a style sheet, and then style the checkbox elements. `float:left; width: 250px` or whatever the styles need to be to fit into your page.

Comment: That might be a workaround in this situation, I would prefer a programmatically solution if it's not too complex and worth the effort. At some point I would need something like this for a Dropdown Field and then  I'm back to square one (would be an almost identical problem, providing certain fields to the Dropdown).

Answer (score 0):

`CheckboxSetField` form field cannot handle different DB fields.
You would need a custom form field (extends `FormField`) to build described functionality.

Alternatively you might use [MultivalueField](https://packagist.org/packages/silverstripe/multivaluefield) that stores selected values in a text db field.

You may use `MultiValueCheckboxField` or `MultiValueDropdownField` for known list.

```
private static $db = array(
  'Amenities' => 'Text',
);

public function getCMSFields() {
  $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
  $fields->replaceField('Amenities', MultiValueCheckboxField::create('Amenities', 'Amenities', $this->getAllAvailableAmenities()));

  return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Hi Greg,
I actually don't want to handle different DB fields in the CheckboxSetField, I just want 3 Boolean fields (Toaster, Microwave, BBQ) of the actual DataObject in the CheckboxSetField. The DataObject has other fields, too, but those should be ignored.